# Does the integration of Intel® Parallel Studio XE 2013 for Linux* and R lead to significant performance improvements?

Tags: r, performance, compiler-construction, intel-mkl, intel-parallel-studio

I am running some resource intensive computations in R. I use for-loops, bootstrap simulations and so on. I have already integrated the Intel® Math Kernel Library for Linux* with R and it seems that this has lead to a significant improvement in computation times. I am now thinking about integrating Intel® Parallel Studio XE 2013 for Linux* and R. This means passing the different compilers that ship with it to R:

(1) Will the integration of Intel® Parallel Studio XE 2013 for Linux* and R lead to significant performance improvements?

(2) Could you give some examples in which situations I would have a benefit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Very* rough order of magnitude:

- parallel / multi-core BLAS such as the MKL will scale sublinearly in the number of cores *but only for the parts of your operations that are actually BLAS calls* ie not for your basic "for-loops, bootstrap simulation and so on"
- byte-compiling your R code may give you up to a factor of two, maybe three
- after that you may need heavier weapons such as for example [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) which can give 50, 70, 90-fold speedups on code involving "for-loops, bootstrap simulation and so on" which why it is eg so popular with the MCMC crowd
- similarly, the Intel TBB and other parallel tricks will require rewrites of your code.

There is no free lunch.

Comment: Thanks! I experienced significant improvement when doing matrix multiplication. Thank you for the link to your page. I will read up on Rcpp.